# iOS App Store Submission Requires a Street Address

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm submitting my first app to the App Store, so I'm working through the form on iTunes Connect. Under the "General App Information" section, it asks for a street address. I do not have a company under which I am submitting the app, so the only address I would have to put there is my home address. Does anyone know if this address will be shown publicly on the App Store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't possibly explain why an off-site vendor decided to require a piece of information at their site. If you have questions about the information Apple requires on their app store submissions or how that information will be displayed or used, ask them.

Comment: @KenWhite My intent was to ask if anyone knows if this address is shown publicly on the App Store, not to ask the philosophy behind Apple's policies. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I commented based on both the title (that you've now changed) as well as the body of your post. If you have questions about app store submissions, contact that app store. This site is for programming related questions, not support for iTunes or the Google App Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not be shown publicly on App Store.
Yes, you can use your home address.